# Need to upload 10gb in a doc library?

Tags: 2010, document-library

How can I upload 10gb of file to sharepoint doc library?

Comment: I just realised, do you have a file that is 2-3 GB in size or multiple files that together have a size of 2-3 GB? If so, how large are the files in general?

Comment: i have 1 file of 2 gb , which i need to upload in document library . I am able to upload upto 1700 . . but when i try for 2 gb i get error screen

Comment: What is the error you receive after 1700 MB?

Comment: Internet explorer could not be found

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general you should't be storing documents of this size in SharePoint. A better approach would be to store it on a file share or FTP and simply link to the file from SharePoint.

You technically cannot store a file larger than 2 GB (2047 MB) to SharePoint. This is the maximum size. If you want to allow files up to 2 GB you'll need to increase the connection time-out in IIS and increase the maximum upload size for the web application. See [SharePoint Large File Upload Configuration](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointcomic/archive/2010/02/14/sharepoint-large-file-upload-configuration.aspx) from (of all places) the TechNet SharePoint comic.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question. If OP is trying to store a 2-3 GB file (i.e. a single file) then my answer applies.

Comment: A better approach would be to store it on a file share or FTP and simply link to the file from SharePoint.How can i do this ?

Comment: You can use a links list, which will allow you to enter a location, and add any metadata columns you need. Just remember you need to configure FTP/file share security too. :)

Comment: Make sure if you do use SharePoint that you are also aware of versioning.  In SP 2010, with versioning on, a simple change of some metadata will create new copies of the large file.

Answer (score 1):

For large size document libraries - you may want to consider RBS (Remote Blob Storage). A few links that may be helpful -

- [To BLOB or not to BLOB. RBS in SharePoint 2010](http://www.sharepointedutech.com/2010/11/30/to-blob-or-not-to-blob-rbs-in-sharepoint-2010/)
- [Overview of RBS (SharePoint Foundation 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748607.aspx)
- [FAQ: SharePoint 2010 Remote BLOB Storage (RBS)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/opal/archive/2010/03/24/faq-sharepoint-2010-remote-blob-storage-rbs.aspx)